# Show 'Developer Tools' when in Google Sheets on a Mac

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets

When in Google Sheets (or any G-Suite app), I can't view the developer console (Command Shift I or View -> Developer -> Developer Tools) like I can on any other Chrome tab.

Is this normal behaviour on a Mac? How can I see the console? I'm running Apps Script apps and there are some client side console logs I need to verify. I can do this on Windows 10 no problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Runs fine for me... Both methods (keyboard shortcut _and_ View->Developer->Developer Tools)

Comment: Maybe not the Mac answer (I don't have a Mac, so can't test), but on Windows in chrome, dev tools don't work in Sheets if the Google Sheets Extension is enabled. If you disable the extension (try running chrome with the --disable-extensions flag if you aren't allowed to disable it by your organization) then the dev tools will work.